# Realtime API - "Maximum Stack Size Exceeded"

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

About 7-8hrs ago we started seeing instances of the "Maximum Stack Size Exceeded" error on our live site. Unfortunately I don't have much information on the error as the relevant bits of the stack have been blown away in the report and I am not able to get it to happen myself. The information I have is the repeated loop and the document ID:

Document ID: 0B0m--69Vv_F6c1gwdUU3OG5MNDQ

Stack

```
...
File https://drive.google.com/otservice/api line 78 col 51 in dl
File https://drive.google.com/otservice/api line 250 col 415 in c.M
File https://drive.google.com/otservice/api line 78 col 51 in dl
File https://drive.google.com/otservice/api line 250 col 415 in c.M
...
```

Will update with more information if it becomes available. Is this happening for others?

Comment: Is this still happening? You haven't made any changes to your code?

Comment: After seeing a fairly large number of instances of this starting ~48hrs ago, I have not seen it again in the last ~20hrs. They started soon after we released a new version of our code ~72hrs ago, but we have not changed anything again since then. I'm a little less concerned about it now and unfortunately don't have more information about what was causing the problem :(. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Just saw another few instances of this although at a reduced rate from before. Looks like it is still happening.

Comment: Looks like there is a bug, I sent you an email with some follow questions.

Comment: Hi Grant,

Do you have a test document which reproduces the error? If so, would you mind sharing it with me?

Unfortunately, the obfuscated stack trace is rather hard to debug.

Comment: Thanks for following up Brian. Unfortunately all of the instances of these errors are in our user's documents rather than in a test document we have access to. Have not had any luck tracking down a document that I can share that this has happened to but will continue looking. I can provide document IDs if that is helpful.

Comment: Hi Brian. I still have not had one of my own documents run into this error, however I am continuing to see a few hits per-day in customer documents. Is there anything other than a direct repro that I can provide to help here?